# Updating database columns based on returned results from a SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table, which is queried from my backend every minute.

```
id (int) | phone_number (string) | start (timedatestamp) | period (string) | occurances (int)
```

I make an sql query, which runs every minute, and returns the results. It's selects all phone_numbers which start this minute.

```
SELECT * FROM table 

WHERE start >= date_trunc('minute', now()) and
      start < date_trunc('minute', now()) + interval '1 minute'

as results
```

This runs fine, but I need to update the table as well, based on this select results.

There are two parts to this:

1. For each selected row, I need the occurrences to decrement by 1 and update the database with this
2. For each selected row, if the periodicity='MONTHLY", I need the start column to change to the date and time exactly a month from now.

Is it possible to do this in one SQL statement? Any help or examples are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: you can save the result of this select into a temp table and update using temp table

Answer (score 0):

Yes and you can do so directly. The only 'twist' is when a column in mentioned in the SET clause Postgres always writes the Rvalue. When you desire to conditionally update a column you set the Rvalue to the existing value when the condition is not meet. See [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4697c12914303a5a5df9be878caa9342).

```
update atable 
   set occurances = occurances-1 
     , start_tm = case when period_txt = 'Monthly' 
                       then now()+interval '1 month'
                       else start_tm
                  end
 where date_trunc('minute',start_tm) = date_trunc('minute',now());
```